# Swipe left or right to Change RecyclerView inside a Fragment

Tags: java, android

I have a Fragment with the following layout:
[Layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1fjl1.png)

I want the RecyclerView that is highlighted to change when onSwipe left/right is called.

Is it easier to have the whole Fragment change?
I have tried this method:
[Android: How to handle right to left swipe gestures](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4139288/android-how-to-handle-right-to-left-swipe-gestures/19506010#19506010) with no success, i get the following exception:

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'float android.view.MotionEvent.getX()' on a null object reference
>                         at com.apps.myshifts.OnSwipeTouchListener$GestureListener.onFling(OnSwipeTouchListener.java:40)

What is the easiest way to implement this?

Comment: Can you add your Activity code to see your gesture listener implementation?

Comment: Why not use a ViewPager?

Comment: @EpicPandaForce So putting the RecyclerView inside a ViewPager would be the easiest way to do it?

Comment: @PFuster I have used this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4139288/android-how-to-handle-right-to-left-swipe-gestures/19506010#19506010 implementation

Comment: well ViewPager pages views based on horizontal drag events, so then you don't need to implement swipe detection yourself

Comment: @Dimon make two lists on different fragments instead of changing it on swipe, unless that breaks the idea.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest I think is to modify your adapter to make it work with multiple lists and when you swipe you clear the RecyclerView, bind the new Data then display it. It is a simple approach that would be good to achieve your goal. You might also try to add some animations to make it look smooth.